# How to have both Javascript divs to be draggable when they are on top of each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several `div`s on top of each other. The top one needs to be draggable and the one below it should still be clickable. I am attaching the picture below so that you can understand more what I mean:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqYzF.png]

The green `div`s are inside in one of the cells. When I click on one of the cells I get the menu above. I want to be able to grag the green divs and if I click inside on of the the `mouseclick` event to be fired upon the cell behind not the parent div.

Here is the html of the divs so that you get a better understanding of the structure:

```
<!-- Spot 00,30 --->
<div id="2_0" class="spot"> </div>

<!-- Spot 15,45 --->
<div id="2_0_1" class="spot"> </div>
<!-- Spot 00,30 --->
<div id="2_1" class="spot" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;"> </div>
<!-- Spot 15,45 --->
<div id="2_1_1" class="spot" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;"> </div>
<!-- Spot 00,30 --->
<div id="2_2" class="spot" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;"> </div>
<!-- Spot 15,45 --->
<div id="2_2_1" class="spot" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;"> </div>
<!-- Spot 00,30 --->
<div id="2_3" class="spot" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;">
<div class="wc-event green ui-draggable" ondblclick="showAppointment(20)" style="display: block; height: 210px;" data-id="20" data-type="booking">
</div>
<!-- Spot 15,45 --->
<div id="2_3_1" class="spot" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;"> </div>
<!-- Spot 00,30 --->
<div id="2_4" class="spot" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;"> </div>
<!-- Spot 15,45 --->
<div id="2_4_1" class="spot" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;"> </div>
<!-- Spot 00,30 --->
<div id="2_5" class="spot" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;"> </div>
<!-- Spot 15,45 --->
<div id="2_5_1" class="spot" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;"> </div>
<!-- Spot 00,30 --->
<div id="2_6" class="spot" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;"> </div>
```

This is for the dark green `div`.

How can I make it so the top div is draggable while the bottom one is still clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can use event delegation to capture events on many elements in one place, you will not be able to trigger the click event of a div that is obscured by another element.